its looks like this app isn't available,Facebook login not working for non administrative/testers users, mobile app react native
In my app i cant login to nonadministrative/nontesters users in facebook login for business, even I have done all the required steps to use facebook login bussiness for both administrative/testers and nonadministrative/nontesters users.
below are the point what i have done but still it is not working for non-administrative/non-testers users, I am getting "its looks like this app isn't available" ERROR, is there any other thing we need to do?

business verify.
Access verify.
email and public profile advance access.
Use data checkup completed.
Configuration added.

we are also attaching images for the point which we have done.
ERROR IN APP
email and public_profile advanced access granted
business and access verification completed and data checkup also
Our App is on LIVE mode also
Configuration added
BUT STILL WE CANT LOGIN ON non-administrative/non-testers users, IS THERE ANY THING OTHER TO DO???????
